# Fill graph background

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, zedgraph

I want to fill the area down to the maximum value in a GraphPane.

[image: Graph]

I think I could create a new filled curve at the background with points seperated by an interval. I could use the FindNearestPoint to find maximum value for a specified x but I'm confused that I should pass mouse coordinates. I have a concrete x in a GraphPane coordinate system, not a mouse x value.

How can I calculate those mouse corrdinates? GraphPane doesn't provide its location. 
Or am I doing it wrong way?

Comment: What color do you want to fill it with? A constant color or the color of either max or min point in given x position?

Comment: @Tarec, constant would be ok if it's simpler.

Comment: @Tarec, are you going to suggest anything? Just thought you may have not received my comment because I didn't mention you (edited afterwise).

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I don't really see any clean way to do that. One of the possibilities is to use a solid background color, take out a bitmap from the control and then draw it manually, but that'd be unefficient for sure. Another way would be to create yourself a custom control, where you'd handle drawing it all on your own, but that's a lot of work. `FindNearestPoint` doesn't have to be invoked with mouse parameters - a custom point will be fine. I'm sorry, but I don't know the control and nothing usefull comes to my mind.